# SSIS to get the particular file from multiple files and copy to different folder

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

my  question is   how we will create SSIS package  to get the particular file from multiple files and copy to different folder
Need Help

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are specifically trying to accomplish.  "get a file" from "multiple files"?   Please help us help you and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use File System Task in your package control flow.

Configure the properties as below:

DestinationConnection: Enter the full file path of the folder you want to move your file to e.g c:\Users\ToTest

Operation: Change to Move file.

SourceConnection: Enter the full file path of the folder where your file is, including the file name and extension e.g c:\Users\Test\testfile.csv

Answer (score 0):

You'll need at least two components.

Use a Foreach Loop container with the default Foreach File Enumerator on the Collection tab. Set `Folder:` to \YourFolder and build an expression under `Files:` to identify the particular file you're interested in.

Inside the Foreach Loop container, add a File System Task to Copy the file from the Source folder to the Destination folder.